# How should I show my Appaloosa horse?

Tags: horses, uk, competitions

I have a three year old Appaloosa filly I will hopefully be showing in-hand this year. (Mostly to help postpone my eagerness to ride.)

I'm wondering what the breed standard is for showing an Appaloosa.
Generally I'd like to show in the English Classical style as these will be small shows but the Western alternative will also be appreciated.

Some main things are:

Mane/Tail

- Plaited?
- Cut?
- Natural?

Coat

- Clipped? If yes, full body?
- Natural?

Hooves

- Oil?

Should I be making anything more apparent/stronger such as markings?